# How to make sure to start SQL Server before the windows service in a software package

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, software-packaging

I have a software package which has web, windows service, and SQL Server components.

I need to make sure that SQL Server is up and running before the service starts - when the machine starts/reboots.

Please suggest a good approach for doing this.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed

Comment: Thank you! But do you know where I should implement it. Has it to be done in all machines where i have installed my package. Or i can handle it in my service code.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is helpful if you want to do such dependency settings in your C# Windows Service itself.

[creating service dependency using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159257/create-dependency-between-windows-services-startup)